# Treemap getting maximum of the values associated with each key

Tags: java

In a treemap,I have each key having multiple values. I have to get only the maximum of each values associated with the key. Can anyone help to do that..

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\book\\geneanno.txt"));
  Map<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String,String>();
  String currentLine;
  while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        String[] pair  = currentLine.split("\\s+");
        key = pair[12];
        value = pair[4]+" ";
        if(map.containsKey(key)){
            value +=  map.get(key);
        } 
            map.put(key,value);
```

The output I get is like this

Key: A1CF  Values : 9168  7541  1478  1001

Key: B547  Values : 1247  7841  1247  3471

But I have to get Output only like this

Key: A1CF Values : 9168

Key: B547 Values : 7841

Comment: What are the keys and values in your map?  Why are you mapping only to a single `String`?  Your code makes very little sense.

Comment: what is input file content?

Comment: A `TreeMap` can't have multiple values for a single key.

Comment: He's manually concatenating the values, so it does 'make sense', although it's not the best way to do it

Comment: Convert your values to int (eg: `int value = Integer.parseInt(valueStr)`, then use `value = Math.max(value, map.get(key))` there instead of appending it to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of concatenating all values in `String`, you could use `TreeSet` where elements will be ordered using their natural ordering.

```
Map<String,Set<Integer>> map = TreeMap<String,TreeSet<Integer>>();
```

And while iterating you could get the maximum value by `TreeSet#last()`, as your value `Set` is naturally ordered.

Comment: Note that you will have to do Integer.valueOf(pair[4]) to get the parsed string as an Integer

Comment: I think that should be `TreeSet#last()` to get the maximum value. `first()` will give the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Subhrajyoti's answer.

You can also do the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

if(map.get(token) == null)
{
   map.put(token,value)
}
else if(map.get(token) < newValue)
{
   map.put(token,newValue)
}
```

Essentially what happens is you will store only the greatest value for every key/ value pair.

This solution is just a tad bit more memory efficient.